# Cucumber not recognizing simple Feature Step

Tags: ruby, testing, scripting, automation, cucumber

I just recently downloaded cucumber and using it for the first time. I am trying to start off with a very simple script, Cucumber --init. Then of course it brings up 0 scenarios and steps. So, then I go to writing. I started off...

```
Feature: Hello Cucumber
```

Then I get this error:

```
'Feature:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: You've created a `.feature` file?  And what command are you running from command line or terminal?

Comment: Thanks for your response. That was the command, Feature: Hello Cucumber. It was in the command prop mt line where I wrote it.

Comment: You need to create a `.feature` file with "Feature: Hello Cucumber" in it and then execute it.  Here's a link to documentation: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Feature-Introduction

Comment: I have done that and each time I follow exactly what it says after initiating cucumber - it keeps giving me that same error. I must not be doing something right. However, Feature :     I dont think I am doing it incorrectly

Comment: Are you referring any tutorial? "Feature" is not a command that you can execute on command prompt.  http://www.guru99.com/your-first-cucumber-script.html

Comment: Yes I am referring to a tutorial. I am just lost on Cucumber I think. Every tutorial I go into as Feature: beginning the test. I cant get one started as I am still confused on this.